# Split CSV file into multiple files sorted my colum

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hi im a Python noob and i want to make a programm to split my csv file into multiple csv files

the file looks something like this:

main.csv

```
Name;Lieferung;Name;Ort;Postleitzahl
somename;60072470;somename;someadress;83620
somename;60071938;somename;someadress;48691
somename;60072194;somename;someadress;13595
somename;60072194;somename;someadress;13595
somename;60072511;somename;someadress;82140
```

and i want the code to automaticly create multiple csv files grouped by Lieferung:

60072470.csv

```
somename;60072470;somename;someadress;83620
```

60071938.csv

```
somename;60071938;somename;someadress;48691
```

60072194.csv

```
somename;60072194;somename;someadress;13595
somename;60072194;somename;someadress;13595
```

60072511.csv

```
somename;60072511;somename;someadress;82140
```

Can someone help me, i did a lot o reaserch but i cant make it :(

THX a Lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```py
import csv

data = {}

with open("input.csv", newline="") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter=";")
    header = next(reader)
    for row in reader:
        data.setdefault(row[1], [])
        data[row[1]].append(row)

for name, row in data.items():
    with open(f"{name}.csv", "w", newline="") as file:
        writer = csv.writer(file, delimiter=";")
        writer.writerow(header)
        writer.writerows(row)
```

Comment: You should fix your answer since the requirements are different, there's an "index" column which he mentions in one of his comments, so you better access the rows by name instead of index.

Comment: @DanielF, what's wrong with this answer? I've run it, and apart from adding a header to every file (which isn't explicitly stated) produces the output OP mocked up. Where do you see mention of an "index"?

Comment: Ali, great answer. Maybe change to `row` to `rows` to better convey the meaning/structure of that var, and so that `writer.writerows(rows)` lines up.

Comment: @ZachYoung Nothing's wrong with it. The issue I was raising was that OP was commenting in another answer that they actual layout is `Index;Name;Lieferung;Name;Ort;Postleitzahl` , which would shift the index by one, and in order to make it more flexible, it would be better to use `row['Lieferung']` (with the according API) instead of `row[1]`. *That comment already got deleted*. I think it was a comment to @qmeeus' answer. But this one here is effectively the correct answer and the reason why I upvoted it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
for Lieferung in df.Lieferung.unique():
    df[df.Lieferung == Lieferung].to_csv(str(Lieferung)+'.csv')
```

You first iterate over the unique `Lieferung` values (print the output of `df.Lieferung.unique()` to see what it does ) and then use these to select only the relevant subset of data (`df[df.Lieferung == Lieferung]`) that you can export to csv using `Lieferung` to create the filename.